# Random runtime exception, not sure what's causing this

Tags: android, exception, runtime

I am getting a runtime exception on the line in my code that sets the content view for the activity. This leads me to believe that my xml file must have an issue that I am simply not seeing. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE: The second TextView is set to blank because the activity associated with this view performs some calculations of which the result will be displayed in the second TextView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ReativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:background="@color/background" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

  <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/results_label_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/results_label" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/results_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text=" "
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</ReativeLayout>
```

Any ideas? I imagine I have something coded wrong here.

UPDATE: Here's the Stack

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
    ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2663  
    ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2679   
    ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 125 
    ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 2033  
    ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
    Looper.loop() line: 123 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4627    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 868  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 626 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Comment: Can we see the stack trace please.

Comment: Post the whole layout, please.

Comment: Stack trace added. Also, that is the whole layout :)
I know that the line "setContentView(R.layout.calculate);" is what is throwing the exception because I added a breakpoint to everyline for the first few lines to see where the app was crashing. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you've solved this by now, but I had a similar problem with setContentView.  After wasting hours checking syntax and spelling and surfing the web, all I had to do was clean the project and it worked perfectly.